# Run app build in 32 bit os on 64bit OS [Ubuntu] bash: no such file or directory, C++, Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

Im running 64 bit OS (Ubuntu 13.04). On my VirtualBox machine I have a Linux Mint 15 32 bit. I build my Qt app on Linux Mint 32 bit and now want to run it on my base OS, installed on my hard drive. But when I want to do this, bash says:

`./app no such file or directory`

I know for sure that `app` is in a given directory, and is executable (did `chmod u+x app`).

Is it possible to run 32 bit Qt app on 64 bit OS?

After installing this: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` I got a new error:

`./app: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

but I have Qt installed on my 64 bit OS!

UPDATE:

Heres what I did (on a machine where I compiled app - 32 bit os):

```
ldd ./app
```

and it gave me:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7775000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xb75b0000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0xb6fa2000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0xb6bc3000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0xb6790000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb66a7000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb6664000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6647000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb6493000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb648e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb6475000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb645a000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb640a000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb6308000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb61d1000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb61a8000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0xb614f000)
    libicui18n.so.48 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.48 (0xb5f7b000)
    libicuuc.so.48 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.48 (0xb5e15000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb5e0c000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7776000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xb5e05000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb5dc4000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xb5da2000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0xb5d8a000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xb5d78000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xb5d74000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xb5d6d000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xb5d6a000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xb5d51000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0xb5d4c000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xb5d46000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0xb5d39000)
    libicudata.so.48 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.48 (0xb4bc8000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xb4bc3000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb4bbc000)
```

I found those files in my 32 bit machine, copied it all, and the executable too, so now I have such dir hierarchy:

[image]

in `platforms` dir I have only: libqlinuxfb.so and libqxcb.so.When I tried to run it on 64 bit OS, I did:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.`

and then:

```
ldd ./app 
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77b4000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xf75e3000)
        libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0xf6fd5000)
        libQt5Gui.so.5 (0xf6bf6000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 (0xf67c3000)
        libstdc++.so.6 (0xf66da000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf6697000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf667a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf64c6000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf64c1000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf64a8000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf648d000)
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf643d000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf633b000)
        libX11.so.6 (0xf6204000)
        libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xf61db000)
        libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-310/libGL.so.1 (0xf60fb000)
        libicui18n.so.48 (0xf5f27000)
        libicuuc.so.48 (0xf5dc1000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf5db8000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77b5000)
        libffi.so.6 (0xf5db1000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xf5d70000)
        libxcb.so.1 (0xf5d4d000)
        libnvidia-tls.so.310.44 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-310/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.310.44 (0xf5d49000)
        libnvidia-glcore.so.310.44 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-310/libnvidia-glcore.so.310.44 (0xf4027000)
        libXext.so.6 (0xf4015000)
        libicudata.so.48 (0xf2ea4000)
        libXau.so.6 (0xf2e9f000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf2e98000)
```

**Now the error I got:**

```
Failed to load platform plugin "xcb". Available platforms are: 
linuxfb
xcb

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. You need 32 bit versions of all shared libraries your program needs. Check if you have Qt 32 bit variant on your machine. See also [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package).

Comment: @n.m. : where can I find these libs?

Comment: Read that link again.

Comment: @n.m.: read this again and again, can you please see my update? the problem still exists

Comment: Does the link say "copy files from a 32-bit machine"? I believe it gives a somewhat different advice. Have you tried it? If you insist on copying files (not a very scalable approach, but whatever floats your boat), try to determine which libraries your app tries to load at runtime (try `strace -f -e open ./app 2>&1 | grep '\.so.*='` on the 32-bit machine).

Comment: @n.m.: I dont insist on anything, cheers ;) I just dont really understand, what was your point giving me this link? I installed `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` on my 64 bit OS but it didnt help at all. Anyway, could you please say in short, what I need to do (step by step) to make a 'linux-portable' qt app? (at least for debian-like OSes?)

Comment: I think the linked question on askubuntu is to confusing, let's try [this piece of documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) instead.